# JQuery slideToggle() - Shows then Hides. Doesn't stay toggled

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, slide

I currently have a clickable div which should implement the slideToggle() function. I've coded it up on JSFiddle - Here it works as it should. However, on my site, it shows then once shown hides its self. So it slides in then out on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/sfvd9aha/19/

// HEADERS

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js">
```

// CSS

```
.info_button{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
.info_text{
    display: none;
}
```

// HTML

```
<form style='text-align:center;' data-ajax="false" id="id_form" method="POST" action="submit.php">
<div class="containing-element">
    <label name='tbl_name'>Label</label>
    <div class='info_container'>
        <div class='info_button'>
        </div>
        <div class='info_text'>
         Here is some text.
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="extra_laps_range_stafford">
    <input type="range" onchange="changedSelector()" data-highlight="true" name="name[]" id="id" value="0" min="0" step="2" max="4"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

// JS

```
$('.info_button').click(function(){   
    $(this).siblings('.info_text').slideToggle();
});
```

Can anyone think of any reason as to what could potentially cause this?

Although not the answer, it has got me closer. 
removing -

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

stopped the problem. However this lib is required for the site. Any suggestions on what could be in here, causing conflicts?

Both the standard Jquery.min lib and mobile.min are loaded to the page.

Thank you all for your comments. They raised questions which lead me to the answer. Just needed to pull in a newer jquery.min.js library. Problem solved, thank you all.

Comment: are you appending data with ajax ?

Comment: what is your site url?Or is there anything below the div

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give the sites URL.

Comment: some css might be restricting it..

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool, Yes it could be that your element and relative element might have conflict in styles.have you checked the console?

Comment: No ajax is being used on the page. Here is some more info, ill put this in the question also:
- Info container is within a form.
- The page uses the mobile version of JQuery, its a mobile site.
- The JS is with $(document).ready(function() {});
- Other divs on the page are shown and hidden based on user selected options. Info boxes are within these div's

Comment: I will adjust the code to show its outer elements.

Comment: Click might be bubbling, causing retoggle. What if you try to use e.preventDefault(); $('.info_button').click(function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();$(this).siblings('.info_text').slideToggle();
});

Comment: have you seen Chilipepper's solution?

Comment: Chilipeppers solution has got me closer to solving it. Edited the main post. Thank you.

Comment: Check rendered HTML, maybe a click event propagation issue. That's said, without all relevant info in question and minimalistic code to replicate issue, this is kind of not useful question

Comment: you can use $.noConflict(); function to avoid conflict with other libraries...

Comment: Unfortunately calling noConflict causes multiple other JQuery related issues. Unless I'm calling it in an incorrect place.

Comment: @SSA just seen your comment, i guess you meant `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Just wondering, does the FORM get submitted?

Comment: It does. Thank you all for your comments. They raised questions which lead me to the answer. Just needed to pull in a newer jquery.min.js library. Problem solved, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works fine on jfiddle, this could be caused by calling jquery twice on your page. Something like this

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well i cant comment on his post, not enough rep, and im just trying to help since i had similar problem in the past ..

Comment: Let him try it, i will delete this post after that

Comment: Although not the answer, it has got me closer. 
removing - <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
stopped the problem. However this lib is required for the site. Any suggestions on what could be in here, causing conflicts?

Comment: Both the standard Jquery.min lib and mobile.min are loaded to the page.

Comment: Is it possible that having the two library's included is causing the function to be run twice?

Comment: oh @portrait..I wrongly flagged your comment...Does anyone know how to remove it

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. They raised questions which lead me to the answer. Just needed to pull in a newer jquery.min.js library. Problem solved, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

It could be all CSSt.  if the size of the area is expanding, it could show, and then gets moved after it renders in the DOM for a split second.